# SQL Query to find out distinct rows of 2 columns using NOT IN

Tags: sql

I request your help very much badly.  Please help me.

I have 2 tables, like below:

**first_table**

```
field1  field2  field3  field4    
======  ======  ======  ======    
A       B       C       D    
A       B       C       D    
A       A       C       B   
A       A       C       B
```

**second_table**

```
field1  field2  field3  field4    
======  ======  ======  ======       
A       B       C       D    
A       B       C       D    
A       A       C       B   
A       A       C       B
```

I need to prepare a sql query as below:

- Fetch the records from `first_table`, which are not present in the `second_table`.
- Further, the query is based on the combination of distinct records from 2 columns like field1 and field2.

For e.g.:

```sql
select first_table.field1, first_table.field2,
       first_table.field3, first_table.field4
from
first_table
where
distinct (first_table.field1 NOT IN second_table.field1 AND first_table.field2 
    NOT IN second_table.field2)
```

But the above query does not work. How can I do this?

Comment: Does it have to use NOT IN for any particular reason? Or any other query that produces the right output is OK? What you are looking for is the records in first_table that do not have matching records in second_table, where a match is having same value in field1 and field2 of each table only?

Comment: i still don't understand what are u trying to do.. (the query is based on the combination of distinct records from 2 columns like field1 and field2) ??

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
select first_table.field1, first_table.field2,
       first_table.field3, first_table.field4
from first_table
where not exists (
    select 1 from second_table
    where second_table.field1 = first_table.field1
    and second_table.field2 = first_table.field2
)
```

This assumes the fields are not allowed to be null. Easy to elaborate for handling null if needed, but the preferred way to do this varies by database.

Answer (score 0):

This query will look for records in first_table that do not have a corresponding record in the second_table. After trying this, specify what exactly do you need, so we can help you.

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4 from first_table as t1
left outer join second_table as t2 on t1.field1 = t2.field1 and t1.field2 = t2.field2
where t2.field1 is null and t2.field2 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but i am giving two querys to you both are working well i think one of them will definietly meet your requirements.

1 .

```
select first_table.field1,first_table.field2,first_table.field3,first_table.field4
     from      first_table
     join second_table
     on first_table.field1 not like second_table.field1 and first_table.field2 not like second_table.field2;
```

2.

```
select first_table.field1,first_table.field2,first_table.field3,first_table.field4 from first_table
 join second_table
 on (first_table.field1  like second_table.field1 and first_table.field2 like          second_table.field2)
   group by first_table.field1,first_table.field2,first_table.field3,first_table.field;
```

I think one of them will help you.